# Discord.js Bot crashing while used command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

my problem is when i write command! Tempmute (user) (time) and in field (time) i'll write for example 10 s / m / h / d it works great but when i wrote other letter in this field bot just crash.
Can any one tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance!
**Code:**

```
  if (command === `${prefix}tempmute`) {
    let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
    if(!tomute) return message.reply("Nie moge znaleźć określonego użytkownika");
    if(tomute.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("Ta osoba ma zbyt wysoką rangę lub nie masz permisji!");
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "muted");

    if(!muterole){
      try {
        muterole =  message.guild.createRole({
          name: "muted",
          color: "#0000000",
          permissions: []
        })
        message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
           channel.overwritePermissions(muterole,{
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false
          });
        });
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
      }
    }

    let mutetime = args[1];
    if(!mutetime) return message.reply("Wprowadź czas na jaki ma byc zmutowana osoba")

    tomute.addRole(muterole.id);
    message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> został zmutowany na ${ms(ms(mutetime))}`);



    setTimeout(function(){
      tomute.id.removeRole(muterole.id);
      message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> został odmutowany!`);
    }, ms(mutetime));

    }
  }

  );
```

**Error in console:**

```
C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\ms\index.js:34
  throw new Error(
  ^
Error: val is not a non-empty string or a valid number. val=undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\ms\index.js:34:9)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\bot.js:241:58)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\pr0mo\OneDrive\Pulpit\Discord Rust Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
```

Comment: Can you try to add a `console.log(mutetime)`? I think it's undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code to the `try catch` statement it won't crash anymore, but if you want to check if the argument corresponds to what you want, you can make an regexp

try catch:

```
try
{

}catch(error)
{
console.log(error)
}
```

Regex:

```
var match = /^(-?(?:\d+)?\.?\d+) *(milliseconds?|msecs?|ms|seconds?|secs?|s|minutes?|mins?|m|hours?|hrs?|h|days?|d|weeks?|w|years?|yrs?|y)?$/i.exec(
    mutetime);
 if(!match)return;
```